# Desenhar usando loop aninhado e incrementação

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando JavaScript por um livro (da editora Casa do Código) e tem um desafio envolvendo loops aninhados, no qual eu tenho que desenhar isso:

[image: Imagem com resultado final do desenho o desafio]

```js
for(var Linha=0;Linha<10;Linha=Linha+1){
  for(var Coluna=0;Coluna<10;Coluna=Coluna+1){
    document.write("*")
  }
  document.write("<br>")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Analisando o desenho:
São 10 linhas e 19 colunas. A cada nova linha, o asterisco da esquerda avança uma casa, o asterisco da direita retrocede uma casa, e onde não há asterisco há um *underscore* ("_").

Então, o script para fazer esse desenho poderia ser escrito dessa forma:

```js
var posAstEsq = 1;   // Posição inicial do asterisco esquerdo.
var posAstDir = 19;  // Posição inicial do asterisco direito.

for (var linha=1; linha<=10; linha++){
  for (var coluna=1; coluna<=19; coluna++){
    if (coluna==posAstEsq || coluna==posAstDir)
      document.write("*")
    else
      document.write("_");
  }
  document.write("<br>");
  posAstEsq++;  // A cada linha o asterisco esquerdo avança uma coluna.
  posAstDir--;  // A cada linha o asterisco direito retrocede uma coluna.
}
```

Ou, pode-se pensar em distância do asterisco, ao invés de posição do asterisco, e nesse caso só uma variável seria usada:

```js
// Distância inicial do asterisco, tanto em relação ao lado
// esquerdo quanto ao lado direito.
// A posição do asterisco esquerdo será sempre 1 + distância.
// A posição do asterisco direito será sempre 19 - distância.
var distAst = 0;

for (var linha=1; linha<=10; linha++){
  for (var coluna=1; coluna<=19; coluna++){
    if (coluna==(1+distAst) || coluna==(19-distAst))
      document.write("*")
    else
      document.write("_");
  }
  document.write("<br>");
  // A cada linha o asterisco se distancia uma coluna do seu ponto de referência.
  distAst++;
}
```